# Is it really necessary to avoid using functions in order for Parse Cloud Code jobs to run for 15 minutes?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I saw from http://profi.co/all-the-limits-of-parse/ that one of the limitations of Parse is:

> - scheduled jobs can last a maximum of 15 minutes, but you have to put ALL of your code in one function (which basically makes it unreadable for later usages)

Is this true? Has anybody verified that you don't get the same 15 minutes of run time if we split the job up into functions?

Answer (score 1):

I have my cloud code in a file like this:

```
module.exports = function(request, status) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(ParseClass);
    query.each(function(classObject){

        return doSomething(classObject).then(function(data),{
            //success code
        }, function(error){
            //error code
        });

    }).then(function(){
        //success code
    }, function(error){
        //error code
    });

    function doSomething(classObject){
        var promise = new Parse.Promise();

        someOtherFunction(classObject.get('variable')).then(function(data){
            promise.resolve(data);
        }, function(error){
            promise.reject(data);
        });

        return promise;
    }

    function someOtherFunction(){
        //code
    }
}
```

It runs fine and hasn't failed.